# Want to remove Folder "." and ".." which I have copied from my phone SD Card?

Tags: directory, delete, sd-card

Here is my terminal code :

```
   root@mehedi-Inspiron-1545:/home/mehedi/SD Card/sdcard/10.5.50.31:2121/PhoneStorage/Download# ls -al
total 46676
drwxrwxr-x  3 mehedi mehedi     4096 জুল    11 05:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 mehedi mehedi     4096 জুল    11 05:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 mehedi mehedi    83277 জুল    10 10:18 17861803_1540974315927302_7704865319494415873_n.jpg
drwxrwxr-x  2 mehedi mehedi     4096 জুল    10 10:18 Adobe Reader
-rw-rw-r--  1 mehedi mehedi    18952 জুল    10 10:18 config.bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 mehedi mehedi   407930 জুল    10 10:18 download_20170115_010150.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 mehedi mehedi    66275 জুল    10 10:18 DVB-T-w-Gliwicach-kierunki-2014.02.17.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 mehedi mehedi  3395403 জুল    10 10:19 Nasi_Lemak,_Mamak,_Sydney.jpg
```

Now can anyone tell me how to delete the folder named . and .. this two was copied from my SD Card.

Comment: Those were not copied from your card.  Those are in every single folder on your system.  `cd .` keeps you in the folder you are in.  `cd ..` takes you up one folder.  The `.` is the present folder you are in, and the `..` is back one folder.

Answer (score 4):

These are standard Linux notations for current directory (`.`) and parent directory (`..`). They have nothing to do with Android or SD card. This is just standard filesystem behavior,and they exist for every directory on the filesystem.

```
$ pwd 
/home/xieerqi/testdir/parent
$ ls -a
./  ../
# going to . directory doesn't do anything, you remain in same place
$ cd .
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/testdir/parent
# going to .. brings you up one level to parent folder
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/testdir
```

Important exception is that with `/` root directory, the `..` will point to itself, since there's no higher directory to go to.

You cannot perform removal on them either (which wouldn't make sense, since you're trying to get rid of your current working directory or its parent):

```
$ pwd 
/home/xieerqi/testdir/parent
$ rm -r .
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
$
```

So what should you do about them ? Nothing. They're part of the Linux package, so to speak. This is not broken, so don't try to fix it.

---

Frequent usage of `.` is via `./` notation. This can be used in case where you'd run a script or executable in your current working directory like `./myscript.sh` or as argument to command, signifying a file in current directory, like `ls ./myfile.txt`. The last approach is often used with globstar to expand to multiple filenames in current directory, such as `ls ./*`. This approach is particularly useful with filenames that may contain leading `-` and thus such filenames may be misinterpreted by commands as arguments, while `./-myfile.txt` avoids that issue.

It's also important to note that since filenames containing leading dot are considered hidden on Linux, these two "pointer" directories can be seen if you explicitly specify for the command that you use to process hidden filenames ( unless your command, such as `find` does that by default).

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63087/85039

Answer (score 0):

These are "hard links" managed by  Linux itself.

Let's create a directory, and have a look at its details:

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ ls -ld dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ravexina ravexina 4096 Jul 11 19:14 dir1/
```

pay attention to the number "2", that's the number of links to this directory (`dir1`) which one of these to is the directory name itself and the other one  is the `.` inside of it.

Let's create a new directory inside of `dir1`:

```
$ mkdir dir1/new-dir
```

now have look at dir1's details:

```
$ ls -ld dir1
drwxrwxr-x 3 ravexina ravexina 4096 Jul 11 19:14 dir1/
```

The number of links became "3", and that's because of `..` inside of `new-dir` which is pointing to the `dir`.

---

There are different usages for these two link, for example with `..` you can relatively move into directories.

One of the most important usages of `.` is to run a shell script inside a directory, what happens when you run a script named `for.sh` just by typing its name? well shell will think that you are trying to run a command named `foo.sh`, it will search for it, can't find it and outputs an error, using `./script` you tell the shell exactly which file you want to run.