# Can't find folder that file was just written to

Tags: directory, jupyter

I just wrote a new config file for Jupyter in my shell:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

The output of that command says:

```
Writing default config to: /home/me/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

I can change the directory in my shell by doing `cd ~/.jupyter/`, but I can't find the folder anywhere in the GUI, which is what I'd like.

How can I find it? Where is this thing exactly?

Comment: What desktop/filemanager? the usual shortcut is Ctrl+H ("Show **h**idden files"). Or see [How to show hidden files in Nautilus 3.20.3 Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837878/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-nautilus-3-20-3-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: Folder/File names starting with a dot are hidden folders/files. To see them in Nautilus press Ctrl+H. To hide them press Ctrl+H again.

Comment: What does this tell us? `ls  ~/.jupyter`

Comment: maybe it's failing silently because the folder isn't there
    mkdir ~/.jupyter

Comment: what @steeldriver said showed me the folder; I didn't realize what `.` indicated or how to see hidden folders. Thanks much for the help

Comment: @snapcrack  This is standard behavior on all Linux/Unix systems. You'll run into this behavior a lot. Also, you might want to be aware of difference between `.` folder and `..` folder.  See for more info this: https://askubuntu.com/a/934929/295286

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the link. I'm very wary of posting garbage noob questions on this channel but for noobs like me, Ubuntu can be tricky. Sorry to everyone for the redundant question

Comment: @snapcrack no problem - we understand that it's hard to search for answers when not familiar with terminology